# A question related to the separable quotient problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have the following question related to the previous posts [Hereditarily indecomposable Banach spaces  and  Separable Quotient problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74171/)  and  [Weak star separable and separable quotient problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79073/)

**Question.** Does every infinite dimensional Banach space  $X$ have an infinite dimensional quotient $Y$ which is isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell^ \infty $.

This is equivalent to the property that the dual $X^*$ has a w* closed subspace $Z$ with its unit ball w* separable. Note that this is not equivalent to the property that $Z$ is w* separable https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5710 .

A possible positive answer to the question will reduce the general **SQP**   to the subspaces of $\ell^ \infty $.

In the case of the subspaces of  $\ell^ \infty $ we know that the infinite dimensional **representable**  subspaces (i.e. subspaces which are analytic as a subset of $\ R^N$ ) have  an infinite dimensional separable quotient https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2032 (Thm. 50) . This class includes the duals of separable Banach spaces.

Comment: @YCor I think that  now is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Here are some thoughts concerning the general **SQP**. Assume that the initial space $X$ does not have a separable quotient. Then $X^*$ does not contain neither an unconditional basic sequence nor a reflexive subspace. By Gowers dichotomy $X^*$ is saturated by separable HI subspaces not containing reflexive subspace.Each one of them is either like Gowers Tree space or its predual. (A terrified  structure for anyone thinking for a counterexample to **SQP**). In the case where $X$ fails **SQP** consider a separable W of $X^*$ which is HI and let $Z^*$ its w* closure.

Comment: Assume that $Z^*$ remains HI . Denote by $Z$  the quotient of $X$ with its dual the space $Z^*$. Choose $(z_n)_n$ a sequence in the  unit ball of $Z$ that norms the space $W$. The sequence $(z_n )_n$ defines a w* continuous operator from $Z^*$ to $l^\infty$ which is isometric on the subspace $W$. Since $Z^*$ is HI this operator is an isomorphism on a subspace of $Z^*$ of finite codimension . Assume that it is isomorphism on the whole $Z^*$. then the unit ball of $Z^*$ is w* metrisable which yields that $Z$ is separable.

Comment: I do not understand "Since $^∗$
 is HI this operator is an isomorphism on a subspace of $^∗$
 of finite codimension". The operator does not range in  $^∗$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Bill The general statement is the following. If $X$ is HI and T a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ then either T is strictly singular or it is isomorphism on a finite codimensional subspace of $X$. The result is included in the  Memoirs  AMS with Tolias. However the statement if $Z^*$ is HI then Z is separable follows immediately from your result that non separable spaces have decomposable dual.

Comment: Non separable Banach spaces $X$ with both $X$ and $X^*$ saturated by HI spaces not containing reflexive subspace seems to me that could exist. But this type of construction admits a resolution of the Identity. Hence has a separable quotient. On the other hand I strongly believe that the dual of non separable subspaces of $l^\infty$ contains an unconditional sequence.

Comment: I see; thanks, Spiros.